# Is 2.1.0-dev or 2.1.0preview1 the more stable version of Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to update my version of Ruby using rbenv. Running rbenv install -l lists all the available versions of ruby, with these two as the only 2.1.0 versions

```
  2.1.0-dev
  2.1.0-preview1
```

Which version of Ruby is more recent and, one assumes, more stable.

Comment: I would generally assume the `dev` version is the bleeding edge build meant for developers, whereas the `preview` version is more stable and aimed at a wider audience as a preview of 2.1.0. So basically, I assume `dev` is more recent but *not* necessarily more stable, since `preview` is probably tested better before release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent stable version is 2.1.1 you can see it here https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/02/24/ruby-2-1-1-is-released/

Comment: hmm, thanks, interesting that it's not listed by rbenv install -

Comment: btw, thanks for the info but since it doesn't technically answer the question, I'm not going to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Hi @Leahcim could you expand on your question please, so maybe I can help you solve it, I initially thought it was about "Which version of Ruby is more recent and, one assumes, more stable" thanks!

Comment: In addition to the information you provided, I  think your answer should also include info about the dev and preview version in order for it to be the accepted answer, otherwise people who come to this page based on the question won't get the answer their looking for.